# This error in Visual Studio 2019 keeps appearing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

so I made a VS 2019 project with a C# form template, and for some reason, after a long while, this error keeps appearing whenever I try to open the designer. I have no idea why this is happening and it's frustrating me. I'm using .NET 5.0

Note: I'm somewhat a beginner with C# & is also my first time asking a question on Stackoverflow.

[image: The error]

Comment: I would suggest that you *start* by updating to VS2022 and .NET 6. Aside from anything else, .NET 5 is no longer supported.

Comment: Please post and code/errors as text, not as an image - [ask]

Comment: Okay, I'll update VS

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: I haven't tried that yet, I'm a busy person & all my drives are red rn so I can't really use VS 2022 since I can't install the things I need for .NET development cause of disk space issues